# get/set the position of a control in a container

Tags: mysql, .net, panel

So i created a software that allows you to drop controls intro its panel move them around and drop controls into those controls and save them into a mysql database.

the problem is that the moment you save the layout and load it back the controls within the controls aren't in the exact same position

so im saving the controls position into a text like this "110:10" and save that text into the database

```
Dim ylocation As String = PointToScreen(c.Location).X & ":" & PointToScreen(c.Location).Y
```

and im loading it back like this

```
Dim esp() As String = Split(.GetString(9), ":")
Dim loc As Point = Me.PointToClient(New Point(CInt(esp(0)), CInt(esp(1))))
```

This is the controls position after saving them
[image: This is the controls position after saving them]

This is the controls position after loading them
[image: This is the controls position after loading them]

Comment: Do you need to convert to screen coordinates and back? Can you just store the actual Location coords, and does that make any difference?

Comment: yes for some reason i precreated a setup of controls and save them and load them
with the pointtoclient theres arround a +/- 10 px from the original location to both coordinates
with its current location for some reason if returns a wayoff location, the original control position is 100,100 using the pointtoclient it returns +/-90,+/-90 and with the location it returns -24,84

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, i was using the me.pointtoclient in the loading script

```
Dim loc As Point = Me.PointToClient(New Point(CInt(esp(0)), CInt(esp(1))))
```

and replaced it with

```
New Point(CInt(esp(0)), CInt(esp(1)))
```

without chaging anything else and it worked perfectly :)